# A dynamic C++ model and a QML ListView

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

I'm using a QML list view which displays one element at a time

```
 ListView
 {
      model: cppobj.list
      ...
 }
```

`cppobj` is a C++ object which can be modified, i.e. items can be removed, appended, etc. If an element is appended, the ListView goes back to the first element. What's more `ListView.onRemove` is not called. Any ideas how to cope with it?

Thanks

/edit: the `append` function of the C++ object looks like that:

```
void append (QString str) { m_list.append(str); emit listChanged(m_list); }
```

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249521/is-it-possible-to-use-qabstracttablemodel-with-tableview-from-qtquick-controls/22265242#22265242)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [QAbstractListModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html). See documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qabstractitemmodel).

Comment: And is there any Model class for QStrings (so that there's less to implement)? the `m_list` in my case was QStringList?

Comment: You can expose `QStringList` through a property, but `QAbstractListModel` is the only way to make the view update on per-item basis.

Comment: And the `QStringListModel` class? It inherits `QAbstractListModel`.

Comment: Yeah, `QStringListModel` would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have a ListModel for variant JSON data that you can use directly in QML, you can have a look at the **JsonListModel**. It can synchronize JSON data to a ListModel so you do not lose the current scroll position of the list. You can also apply transition animations and have the full ListView/ListModel features available.

```
 ListView
 {
      model: JsonListModel {
          source: myJsonData
          keyField: "id"
      }
      ...
 }
```

You can find a detailed guide how to use the JsonListModel [here](https://v-play.net/apps/avoid-cpp-models-qt):