# QtQuick QML SQL C++

Tags: c++, sqlite, qml

I need to run an algorithm in Qt on data that originates  from two different sources:

1- UART  ( raw transducer data)
 2- variables a user inputs into a gui

The result is then output to the gui for the user to see

Gameplan:
 - User inputs variables via a gui (written in qml - i actually have no choice on this)
 - The qml creates a database of all variables, then 
-  Invokes C++ routines for collecting raw  data over a UART , saves it to a file, 
- the C++ module opens up the database and extracts variables needed , opens the file reads in the data, runs the algorithm using both, calculates the answer and writes it to the database, 
- program then jumps back to QML where, later, the QML will go into the database to extract that answer and display it.

If you see a flaw already please let me know before I spend hours finding out this wont work. If it is plausible.....

FOUR QUESTIONS:
(1)   who should run the  UART  -  C++ or QML?   anyone knows pros /cons?  The raw data will have to be post processed so i'm thinking it will need file saving (I'm thinking UART is a C++ thing)

(2)  I need to create a database from user input variables from QML - any one have examples of this?

(3)  - the QML  must do a Q_INVOKABLE to the C++  routines (to run the algorithm) .  I've already run a test program to prove I can do that so not too worried though if anyone has any other examples I'd love to see how others do this.

(4) BOTH the QML and the C++ need to access (read and write) the database created in (2).
Is this doable?   If so...anyone have any examples of QML and C++ sharing the same database, any code, videos, anything?     Should I keep opening and closing the database or is there a way to open it and have some pointer or something be passed around. I can't find anything about QML accepting or passing a pointer.

Thanks
Dubs

(using ARM® Cortex™-A9  embedded linux qt)

Comment: You'll probably have better luck asking this on the [interest mailing list](http://lists.qt-project.org/mailman/listinfo/interest) or [forum](https://forum.qt.io/category/11/mobile-and-embedded). The question is too broad and will likely lead to opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL and QML `Q_INVOKABLE` refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249521/is-it-possible-to-use-qabstracttablemodel-with-tableview-from-qtquick-controls/22265242#22265242) and for UART use **C++** and invoke it from QML.